# What has happened to this site?

Tags: support, meta, community-user

The whole front page (of this site, meta) is old questions modified 3 hours ago by Community. What's going on here?

Comment: See the answer to http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13483/what-is-the-community-user-doing

Comment: Ah. I guess that explains it. What a mess!

Comment: "*And I looked, and behold a pale horse: and his name that sat on him was Community Bot, and Hell followed with him.*" - Renovations 6:8, King SE Bible.

Comment: @AsafKaragila "The trouble with computers is that they're very sophisticated idiots" -- Tom Baker, "Robot"

Comment: @YemonChoi not sure this fits the situation.

Comment: @Yemon: What quid said.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The site https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ played for a long time a dual role, that of the meta site for Stack Overflow but also that of a meta site for the entire Stack Exchange network.

Recently this was changed and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ became https://meta.stackexchange.com/ while https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ was restarted as a meta site purely for Stack Overflow.

As a consequence of this split some links we had to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ were updated.

This did not go as planned. On the one hand things got bumped, and on the other hand some things got broken. The SE team is aware of the problem, in general and for our site specifically (though basically all sites are affected); see for example [Community ♦ bot doesn't like markdown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230288/community-bot-doesnt-like-markdown)

---

Update: According to a recet comment on the linked post, what was broken should be fixed by now (and indeed the posts got edited a second time, yet now, though hardly relevant,  not bumping them again). Thus, in case something should still be broken (as opposed to only being bumped) it could make sense to report it.