# Misspelling of Cauchy-Schwarz

Tags: support, editing, moderation, bumping

As [a comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21604/nice-proof-of-the-triangle-inequality-for-the-metric-of-the-hyperbolic-plane#comment783489_21608) of Dennis Serre, the correct spelling of Cauchy-Schwarz is Cauchy-Schwarz (not Cauchy-Schwartz):

> The spelling is Cauchy-Schwarz, from Hermann Schwarz. If you are interested in Fourier transform and distributions instead, then you probably mean Laurent Schwartz.

A simple search gives us 72 results for Cauchy-Schwartz in MO, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=Cauchy-Schwartz). 
Is there a way to correct this misspelled word without bumping? Or should an ordinary user correct this misspelled word?

Comment: Personally, I would fix it on newly written or edited posts and otherwise leave it. It is unfortunate but there is no cause for confusion, and I prefer not to clutter the main page with edits.

Comment: This seems like the kind of stuff we can request the developers to run an automated search/replace and not bump posts. I'd guess that it would be better if we can find a few other commonly misspelled phrases or some other variants of "C-S" (e.g. with en-dash or em-dash or no dash).

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by saying: "Community user (machine) in MO corrected some similar spelling"? I am unaware of some edits which were done automatically (and without bumping) with two exceptions: One of them was [change from http to https](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058) (around March/April 2017?) and the other one was the [move from Meta Stack Overflow to Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212631) (March/April 2014?). In fact, due to some mistakes the latter [caused some bumping](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1657) due to some bugs.

Comment: Some edits may *appear* as if they were done by community user, but there was actually a human actor behind them. (IIRC those are edits suggested by anonymous user and also if reviewer chooses "Approve and Edit" when reviewing a suggested edit.) For more details, see: [Modified by Community](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1636).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thanks for your explanations. I  edited the question, accordingly

Comment: I do not know the whether it is likely that SE will be willing to do something like this using some automation. However, I will at least add links related to manual edits. The FAQ entry [Editing etiquette](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2208) touches also misspellings. Probably this is also relevant: [Do we have an unofficial quota on how many old questions one should bump for minor edits in a single day?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/599) (And of course, implementing this feature request would make things easier: [Minor edits, subject to review](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/192).)

Comment: @AsafKaragila When you suggest to collect some common misspellings, you mean collecting frequently misspelled words in general (such as continuous $\to$ continuous) or just names of mathematicians (such as Haussdorff $\to$ Hausdorff)? Would you include also stuff such as Erdos $\to$ Erdős? In case it is useful, some names which are often misspelled are mentioned in this post on Mathematics Meta: [Searching for accented characters is too strict](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8698#8709).

Comment: Does it make sense to correct Cauchy-Schwarz without correcting the other incorrect Schwartz/Schwarz confusions?  I say, make such minor corrections only when the post is bumped to the front page for some other reason.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Your example "(such as continuous → continuous)" seems to have a mis-misspelling.

Comment: @jeq Sorry, I meant [continous](https://mathoverflow.net/search?tab=active&q=continous).

Comment: [@jeq](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3952/misspelling-of-cauchy-schwarz#comment17509_3952), looks like [it](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3952/misspelling-of-cauchy-schwarz#comment17500_3952) was a missed mis-misspelling.  :-)

Comment: Referenced in [an Über meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383433/can-the-link-replacement-tool-be-used-on-typos-in-regular-text) in 2022.